# Sequelize "Self-referential super many-to-many relation"

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js, many-to-many

The sequelize doc said about **Self-references** and **super many-to-many** in the same page [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html#self-references). But does it supports combination of two?

Is there any example for "Self-referential super many-to-many relation"?